# sessionStorage works but localStorage gets JSON.parse error, what's the difference?

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage, session-storage

The following code works if I make a single change: replacing `localStorage` with `sessionStorage`.

Can someone explain why? To my knowledge, they are identical in functionality and differ only in that sessionStorage is limited to a tab.

```
  read(key: string): any {
    const item = localStorage.getItem(key);
    return JSON.parse(item);
  }

  write(key: string, value: any): void {
    localStorage.setItem(`${key}`, JSON.stringify(value));
  }
```

Comment: In both cases I get a typescript error because `item` could be `null` and you cannot call `JSON.parse(null)`.  This might help: `return item ? JSON.parse(item) : undefined;`.  If that's not it, please update your post with the exact text of the error that you are getting.

Comment: Clearing the cache solved this. Likely the issue was caused due to a previous oversight of not using `stringify`, which ended up storing invalid content.